# Flutter- How to resize height and width of an image in custom Paint?

Tags: dart, flutter

Here I am passing a list of the image to ImagePaint class to clip image in a circular, Its fine the images are clipping but only clipping some part of the image, If I could decrease this height and width of the image. Then it will fit the circle, Please comment if any have an idea.

```
void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
int c = 0;
canvas.save();
canvas.translate(size.width / 2, size.height / 2);
canvas.rotate(-rotation);

for (var i = 0; i < 16; ++i) {
  if (i % 2 == 0) {
    canvas.drawLine(
      new Offset(0.0, 0.0),
      new Offset(0.0, size.width / 2 - 4.2),
      tickPaint,
    );
  } else {
    canvas.save();
    canvas.translate(-0.0, -((size.width) / 2));
    canvas.clipPath(path);
    if (images[c] != null) {
      ui.Image img = images[c];
      canvas.drawImage(img, Offset(0.0, 0.0), new Paint());
    }
    canvas.rotate(2 * pi);
    canvas.restore();
    c++;
  }
  canvas.rotate(2 * pi / 16);
}
canvas.restore();}
```

This image is printed in a circular manner:
[image: this image is printed in a circular manner]

This is my app I am clipping image and printing in circular:
[image: This is my app I am clipping image and printing in circular]

Comment: I haven't checked the canvas yet in flutter but can you try the "ClipOval" to clip images in the oval?

Comment: Why do you want to draw them manually instead of using a `Image` directly?

Comment: Because I want to rotate this, manually using my finger, If any other way to rotate and print image in circular using widget please comment.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50960684/how-to-display-circular-image-using-custompaint-class-in-flutter

Comment: Problems have been solved.
`ui.Image img = images[c];
          final ui.Rect rect = ui.Offset.zero & new Size(200.0, 120.0);
          final Size imageSize = new Size(330.0, 230.0);
          FittedSizes sizes =
              applyBoxFit(boxfit, imageSize, new Size(100.0, 200.0));
          final Rect inputSubrect =
              Alignment.center.inscribe(sizes.source, Offset.zero & imageSize);
          final Rect outputSubrect =
              Alignment.center.inscribe(sizes.destination, rect);

          canvas.drawImageRect(img, inputSubrect, outputSubrect, new Paint());`

Answer (score 7):

I just figured out how to reduce the image and send it to the painter for drawing.

The method that shrinks the image and what it returns is sent to the drawing class.

If it works for you, thank me for my reply with a thumbs up, thanks.

```
import 'dart:ui' as ui;
import 'package:image/image.dart' as IMG;

Future<ui.Image> loadImage( List<int> data ) async {
   final IMG.Image image = IMG.decodeImage(data);
   final IMG.Image resized = IMG.copyResize(image, width: 200);
   final List<int> resizedBytes = IMG.encodePng(resized);
   final Completer<ui.Image> completer = new Completer();

   ui.decodeImageFromList(resizedBytes, (ui.Image img) => completer.complete(img));
   return completer.future;
}
```

Drawing class.

```
class CustomDraw extends CustomPainter {
  final ui.Image image;

   const CustomDraw({this.image});

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    canvas.drawImage(image, new Offset(40.0, 10.0), paint);
  }

   @override
   bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
     return false;
   }
}
```